# how to init uiView frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, swift3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw0KF.png)Hi i made one UIView in objective c and in .m File i initialize like this. so i can initialize frame in any view
and in setupDefaultAttributes i set default property of elements

```
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
        [self setupDefaultAttributes];
    }

    return self;
}
```

now i want to use this code in Swift

how can i do this? when i tried this code in swift i am getting this error

Property 'self.delegate' not initialized at super.init call

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about your exact requirement but for the above objective c Syntax , you can use below code.It may help you to achieve your taget

```
 override init(frame: CGRect) {

  super.init(frame: frame)
  setDefultAttributes()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setDefultAttributes(){

}
```

[image]

Comment: Property 'Self.newFrame' not initialized at Super.initcall this error giving me on this line super.init(frame: frame)

Comment: can you please share a screenshot if possible for the code you have written and the error which you are getting.

Comment: i uploaded image please see it

Comment: can you please check weather you have initialized it earlier or not. Also check if you are extending UIView nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must override init method (without parameters) where you should initialize newFrame property
( existing method leave as is just add new one)